# Input loses focus when changing state in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to filter through data from the Rick and Morty API that can be found here : https://rickandmortyapi.com/

this is the code I have :

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "./components/Card.js";

function App() {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [query, setQuary] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFn = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${query}`
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        setCharacters(data);
      } catch {
        setIsError(true);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchFn();
  }, [query]);

  
 

  if (isError) return <div>oops</div>;

  if (isLoading || !characters) return <div>w8 bro</div>;

  const cardList = characters.results.map((character) => {
    return <Card key={character.id} {...character} />;
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <form className="input-group rounded">
          <input
            type="text"
            className=""
            placeholder="Search"
            onChange={(e) => setQuary(e.target.value)}
            value={query}
          />
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="characters--container">{cardList}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So what I am currently doing is getting the value from the input, and changing the state 'query', that I use on my link to fetch the data. It is working, I get the data that I want, and display them, but every time I type a letter on the input box the cursor stops and I have to click again to type the next letter. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're completely removing the `<input>` element when you pre-emptively return with `if (isLoading || !characters) return <div>w8 bro</div>;`

you can fix this by removing that line and changing another

```js
  const cardList = characters?.results.map((character) => {
    return <Card key={character.id} {...character} />;
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <form className="input-group rounded">
          <input
            type="text"
            className=""
            placeholder="Search"
            onChange={(e) => setQuary(e.target.value)}
            value={query}
          />
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      {isLoading || !characters ? (<div>w8 bro</div>) : (<div className="characters--container">{cardList}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
```

I've made the changes in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-feather-3xdw1x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I noticed that you added a ? on characters.result.map on cardList. It doesn't work otherwise. Could you explain what that is, or guide me to a source that does?

Comment: @GeorgeIliopoulos this is a thing called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It's a relatively new feature in JS. It does the same thing as `.`, except if the left side is `undefined` or `null`, it won't do anything on the right side and just return `undefined`. Another way to approximately achieve this functionality is by saying `characters && characters.results.map(...)` (note: if the thing on the left is `null` this will return `null` instead of `undefined`)

Comment: also note that `&&` ([Logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)) does not itself always return a boolean, it returns the "first [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) operand encountered when evaluating from left to right, or the value of the last operand if they are all [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)."

Comment: Thank you! Would that mean that if my fetch doesn't return any data, my page shouldn't break? Like trying to give to the input a value that won't return a page, you get an error that comes from the map function. But since characters is undefined in that case, wouldn't it stop it from happening?

Comment: @GeorgeIliopoulos correct. (as an example) if you had `let foo = undefined;` and `foo.bar`, this would throw an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bar')`, however if you did `foo?.bar` this would not throw an error and instead would silently evaluate as `undefined`